# How do you install drivers for the AMD Radeon R7 m360 graphics card?

Tags: radeon, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

There is no Linux drivers on the AMD site for the Radeon R7 m360 and I was wondering how you would install those drivers in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does any options show up in Additional Drivers? You can type "Additional Drivers" in the Dash or go to System Settings > Softwares & Updates > Additional Drivers tab to show up this window.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this graphics card for a couple of days now (June 2016) with Xubuntu 16.04. I am using the open source driver provided by the system, though there is no mention made of this card being supported when one looks through Xorg logs. There seems to be a binary driver listed on the AMD website, but I have not tried it.

I did have to set "nomodeset" in /etc/default/grub and had to specify the screen resolution in the grub file to get it to boot decently, otherwise it was a no go. Hopefully AMD/ATI works on adding this card to the open source drivers they have been working on.

Comment: Is your driver R7 M360? I can't get mine work on ubuntu 16.04..

Comment: My card is that, but the driver is the generic one. I tried the AMD-PRO driver that was recently released, but as it disabled all sorts of things possible because it is a beta, I just uninstalled it.